# Capture Git output in a Bash variable

Tags: command-line, bash, git, mingw64

I want to capture a command execution output like below:

```
$ o=$( git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git )
Cloning into 'demo'...
remote: Counting objects: 176, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
remote: Total 176 (delta 84), reused 162 (delta 77)
Receiving objects: 100% (176/176), 32.98 KiB | 2.75 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (84/84), done.

$ echo "$o"
    # Empty.
```

OK, just call me stupid, I haven't redirected the output. So:

```
$ o=$( git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git 2>&1 )
```

Printed nothing in my console so I started being optimistic and continued to:

```
$ echo "$o"
Cloning into 'demo'...
```

And this is all. The other many lines printed by `git` were simply not stored into my humble `o` variable.

Then I tried to run the command in a subshell then redirect:

```
$ o=$( (git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git) 2>&1 )

$ echo "$o"
Cloning into 'demo'...
```

What is it going on here?

---

Note: I tried to do my homework but posts like [How do I store the output of a git command in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186162/how-do-i-store-the-output-of-a-git-command-in-a-variable) just tell me exactly the first thing I've tried and failed. Many other links just repeat the same.

Comment: Does `$ o=$( git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git </dev/null 2>&1 | cat )` make any difference? ( That is an attempt to make git NOT have a console/terminal )

Comment: Hi @Hannu. It gives the same simplified output.
A friend helped me and pointed that `--progress` solves the problem. I'll ask him to post an answer.
Thanks!

Comment: You know, you CAN post an answer to your own question! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The answer:

*Add `--progress` to `git clone` to force printing progress.*

#### Explanation:

OK, I made a lot of homework now.

[Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) was quite subttle:

> --progress
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default ***when it is attached to a terminal***, unless --quiet is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

So, since it was *not* printing progress, `git`, for any reason, considered that it was *not* connected to a terminal.

My naïve understanding tried to read this:

```
$ o=$( git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git 2>&1 )
```

As if both `stdout` *and* `stderr` would map to the same `pts` so I ran some `lsof` in 3 different scenarios.

##### 1: Just run command, without capturing

```bsh
$ git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git
```

```bsh
$ bash -c '{ lsof -a -p $(pidof git)  -d0,1,2; }'
COMMAND   PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
git     39542         j4x    0u   CHR  136,7      0t0     10 /dev/pts/7
git     39542         j4x    1w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 233734 /dev/pts/7
git     39542         j4x    2w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 233734 /dev/pts/7
```

##### 2: Capture output, no redirection

```bsh
$ o=$( git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git )
```

```bsh
~ $ bash -c '{ lsof -a -p $(pidof git)  -d0,1,2; }'
COMMAND   PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
git     39859         j4x    0u   CHR  136,7      0t0     10 /dev/pts/7
git     39859         j4x    1w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 233734 /dev/pts/7
git     39859         j4x    2w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 233734 pipe
```

I sillily expected it to print the same way as "1:", but I was wrong and discovered that Bash uses a `pipe` to capture the process output and write it to a variable.

I didn't know that!

##### 3: Capture output, redirect `stderr`

```bsh
$ o=$( git clone git@my.server:my-repo/demo.git 2>&1 )
```

```bsh
~ $ bash -c '{ lsof -a -p $(pidof git)  -d0,1,2; }'
COMMAND   PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
git     40170         j4x    0u   CHR  136,7      0t0     10 /dev/pts/7
git     40170         j4x    1w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 233734 pipe
git     40170         j4x    2w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 233734 pipe
```

Now it all makes sense!

**A `pipe` is not a tty ([`isatty()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)) and since `git` checks for a tty on `stderr`, progress won't print. You need to force it with `--progress`.**

I hope this will be useful for anyone else.

#### References

- [Illustrated Redirection Tutorial](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)
- [How bash redirection works under the hood](https://brandonwamboldt.ca/how-bash-redirection-works-under-the-hood-1512/)
- [git-clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)
- [isatty()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)